# adding button to top right of block level elements

Tags: html, css

How would I add a button to the top right of block level elements? Lets say i have :

```
<div>some content here</div>
```

and lets say this content is long enough to make a "block", how would I format to have a button at the TOP RIGHT of the block, right next to the block that is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(1) One way is to float the `button` right at the top of the container.

```
<div><button>My Button</button>some content here</div>

div + button {
float: right;
}
```

(2) Another way is to position the `button` absolutely inside the `div` container and give the `div` container *position* (so that elements postioned absolutely inside it are relative to this container). This way the button can be anywhere in the markup, providing it is inside the container.

```
div {
position: relative;
}

div button {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

However, the button will now be on top of other content inside the container so you might have to adjust this with padding etc.

Comment: @Praneet Do you mean flush to the inside of the block? Both methods (1) and (2) above should do this. If (1) does not then you probably have some padding on your outer container.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely position it:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    some content here
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;"><input type="button" value="x" /></div>
</div>
```